# loading gif with ajax request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, dom

```
 $(".content-short").click(function() {
      var ID = $(this).attr('data-id');
      $('.loadingmessage').show(); 
      $.ajax({   
          type: "post",
          url: "collegeselect.php",
          data: 'ID=' + ID,
          dataType: "text",                  
          success: function(response){                    
              $(".content-full").html(response); 
              $('.loadingmessage').hide(); 
          }
      });
    });
```

//collegeselect.php// is for loading data from database, //.loadingmessage// is for gif

when i am using this for the first time it displays gif,but the gif is not displayed  after the  1st click as the data retrieved is already available in content-full from previous ajax request,
how to display it on every click on content short class?

Comment: Does collegeselect return an image/gif or an `<img src="...." />` ? You are requesting text

Comment: sorry i just edited the code,.
//collegeselect.php// is for loading data from database, //.loadingmessage// is for gif @mplungjan

Comment: So your problem is that the loading gif is not showing?

Comment: the return from the php is type "text" @mplungjan

Comment: it displays for the first click, but not afterwards @mplungjan

Comment: Share related HTML as well, we don't find any error according to your codes.

Comment: when i click on content-short it shows gif inside content-full, but any click on content-short does not display the gif,and also content-full is already populated with previous ajax request result @jogesh_pi

Comment: As you said **content-short it shows gif inside content-full**, your gif replace with the response of ajax request `$(".content-full").html(response);` so from the next time it will not display because it doesn't exists.

Comment: but i have used  $('.loadingmessage').show();  on every content-short click with new ajax request.@jogesh_pi

Comment: Just show the HTML :) (a minimal example if the content is long please) - that way the explanation is easier

Answer (score 0):

That happens because you are replacing the actual content with loading GIF image with your response.

So, when you click first time it displayed and after the ajax call sucess as per the code you have replaced the content of `.content-full` and there is no GIF available then.

***Solution :*** To resolve either send the same image tag with response or Move the loader image out side the `.content-full`.

Comment: but i have used $('.loadingmessage').show(); on every content-short click with new ajax request     @Toretto

Comment: @AryanKanwar as '.content-short' is class it apply for each element with the same class.

Answer (score 0):

Add `beforeSend : function()` before success in your request.

try

```
$(".content-short").live(function() {
      var ID = $(this).attr('data-id');
      $('.loadingmessage').show(); 
      $.ajax({   
          type: "post",
          url: "collegeselect.php",
          data: 'ID=' + ID,
          dataType: "text",
          beforeSend : function()
          {
            $('.loadingmessage').show();
          },
          success: function(response){                    
              $(".content-full").html(response); 
              $('.loadingmessage').hide(); 
          }
      });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

From the comments, I gather that the `img` is within the `.content-full` container.  The problem is that the `img` is removed when ajax succeeds since you're doing `$(".content-full").html()`. One way to fix it is to move the `img` out of the container. Another way is to store a reference to the `img` and add it back along with the response via `.append()` or `.prepend()` as below.

```
$(".content-short").click(function() {

    var ID = $(this).attr('data-id');
    $('.loadingmessage').show();

    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "collegeselect.php",
        data: 'ID=' + ID,
        dataType: "text",                  
        success: function(response) {

            var $content = $(".content-full");
            var $loaderImg = $content.find('.loadingmessage').hide();
            $content.html(response).prepend($loaderImg);
        }
    });
});
```

Here is [a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/39jn3utm/) mimicking the behaviour thru `setTimeout`.

Comment: the webpage becomes unresponsive using your method afterfew clicks @Ishettyl

Comment: The 3 lines of code I have added cannot make your page unresponsive unless you click million times a second!. There must be something else that's not behaving!